# foreign key and locking

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to set foreign key between empty table to full table but for some reason the setting not completed since it got stuck (never encounter this behaviour before). I am using MSSQL. is setting foreign key locks the tables?

Answer (score 1):

While creating a foreign key ,SQLserver will need to obtain `SCH-M` lock on Parent and Child table..SCH-M lock is not compatible with any lock,so it will wait until it is granted the lock..This is the reason why you are seeing Process as stuck

You can check why it is blocked using below queries..

--blocked by/wait type

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id='your sessionid where foreign key script is being run'
```

--locks

```
select * from sys.dm_tran_locks where request_session_id='<<spids of FK scipt session>>'
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. The first query returned empty and I don't have permission to execute the second query.

Comment: it seems you are lacking permissions